# Верстка навигационного меню

Tags: вёрстка, меню

Пытался как мог, но не выходит установить меню должным образом. То выглядит убого, то еще что-нибудь. Накидал в фш как это схематично выглядеть должно. Пните хотя бы в нужную сторону, пожалуйста.[image: Схематичный вид меню]

Comment: Добавь твой код

Comment: решил вопрос с помощью transform: skewY(20deg); Если будут другие варианты, то было бы интересно узнать. (если нужно могу свое решение выложить, как только разберусь с выкладыванием кода на сайте :) )